# play an avi video file in java swing

Tags: java, swing, video, user-interface, avi

I need to play an avi video file and add it to a jpanel.  All I need to be able to do is to play from beginning to end of the video and then proceed with my program.  I don't need any seek functions or anything like that.  What is the simplest way of doing this? preferbly without using xuggler if possible

Comment: I have never tried it, but [vlcj](http://code.google.com/p/vlcj/) could be a promising option.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It easy to embed the VLC player inside a swing application using [VLCJ](http://caprica.github.io/vlcj/). Here is a working example:

```
 public class PlayerPanel extends JPanel {

     private File vlcInstallPath = new File("D:/vlc");
     private EmbeddedMediaPlayer player;

     public PlayerPanel() {
         NativeLibrary.addSearchPath("libvlc", vlcInstallPath.getAbsolutePath());
         EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent videoCanvas = new EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent();
         this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
         this.add(videoCanvas, BorderLayout.CENTER);
         this.player = videoCanvas.getMediaPlayer();
     }

     public void play(String media) {
         player.prepareMedia(media);
         player.parseMedia();
         player.play();
     }
 }

 class VideoPlayer extends JFrame {

     public VideoPlayer() {
          PlayerPanel player = new PlayerPanel();
          this.setTitle("Swing Video Player");
          this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
          this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
          this.setSize(640, 480);
          this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
          this.add(player, BorderLayout.CENTER);
          this.validate();
          this.setVisible(true);

          player.play("http://174.132.240.162:8000/;stream.nsv");
     }

      public static void main(String[] args) {
          new VideoPlayer();
      }
 }
```

Comment: so, vlc media player has to be installed in the computer in order it to be working?

Comment: Yes or you can add it to a subfolder of your swing project.

Comment: thanks... but I doubt it's platform dependent because of different vlc for different platforms?

Comment: Yes it is platform dependent.

Comment: how can we add vlc controls ?

Comment: http://capricasoftware.co.uk/#/projects/vlcj/tutorial/basic-controls