# java awt/swing: how do you play video?

Tags: java, awt, jmf

I've been googling how to play video files. Firstly, I came across JMF but then realized it is nowadays obsolete.

Then, I found "xuggle" but it seems quite difficult to use that with my knowledge.

Could anyone of you tell me how do you usually play video using java?

Thank youuu!

Comment: Go with JavaFX2: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18758041/play-a-video-using-javafx

Comment: this works for java 8, right? I'm not using java 8...

Comment: Or use (VLC player)[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16962013/play-an-avi-video-file-in-java-swing/16962305#16962305] with VlcJ. It needs the player to be downloaded as well, but then you can do all the VLC can, i.e. connect to streamings.

Comment: JavaFX can work starting with Java 7.

Comment: after watching this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uRK6MHlBi-0

I got something working! thanks a lot!