# Video as a background JAVA GUI

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I am designing a simple GUI game for my OOP module assignment. 
I have an Adventure Game that is text-based. 
My t Interface currently looks like this: 
[Characters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrRE.png)
[Start](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FGwNO.png)

I am pretty new to Java Swing and I was wondering if there is a way to put a video as a background on those two menus. A small looping video will do the job, but looking through Google and StackOverflow couldn't find an answer. 
I am intending to do something like the World of Warcraft menu background (video on the back while your browsing through the menu).

Comment: What about a GIF?

Comment: Would that be easily scalable?

Comment: Do you mean a video that shows those two images? I really dont understand what you intend to do? And honestly: if that is a homework assignment: go simple first. Make things work, do all the mandatory things. Then step by step enhance the UX for example. Beyond that: your question is not only unclear but also too broad.

Comment: I edited my question, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the approach described in [play an avi video file in java swing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16962013/play-an-avi-video-file-in-java-swing) and integrate a VLC Player in your swing front-end.

Comment: I think that is what I am looking for. Thank you!